# What is the difference (and english translation) between 风浪 and 涌浪?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice, mandarin, synonyms

As far as I can tell, 风浪 is waves created by wind, and 涌浪 would be waves created by tidal movements or surge waves. However, this is a very bulky way to describe them. What is the English for this difference, besides just "wave"?

Google translate offers the alternative options of 风浪: wind and waves, storm; for  涌浪: swell, surge 
English has "storm surge", but that's not really helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www2.ouc.edu.cn/cpeo/oceanography/ziyuan/tech/chapter8/6.htm) webpage from the *Ocean University of China*, '风浪'='wind wave', and '涌浪'='swell'.
That webpage also gives the following definitions:
风浪(wind wave): They are generated by the wind, restored by gravity, and progress in a particular direction.
涌浪(swell):When the waves move out of the storm center, forced waves become free waves moving at speeds due to their periods and wavelengths. Once away from the storm these long-period, uniform waves are called swell.

According to the Wikipedia definition of [Swell (ocean)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swell_%28ocean%29), the swells are
"*These series of surface gravity waves are not generated by the immediate local wind, instead by distant weather systems, where wind blows for a duration of time over a fetch of water. This is the primary definition of a swell as **opposed to a locally generated wind wave**, which is still under the influence of the mechanisms that created it e.g. Wind blowing over a puddle.*"

To my understanding, '风浪' has two meanings. The broader meaning refers to all waves generated by wind blowing; the narrower meaning refers to "a locally generated wind wave, which is still under the influence of the mechanisms that created it", to distinguish from '涌浪'.